# Bower package not working in Sublime

Tags: npm, bower

I installed the Bower package for Sublime. It says Bower is installed, but when I try to install anything I get this warning:

> bower could not be found in your $PATH. Install bower with `npm install bower -g`

I'm a noob when it comes to using Terminal, but I tried to install Bower there. But it comes back with:

> -bash: npm: command not found

It appears this relates to Node, but I don't even know what that is or anything about it.
I'm on a Mac 10.6.8., using Sublime Text 2. If this solution requires going back into Terminal, please spell it our for me, because I am not comfortable using it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Man, people are hardcore with the downvotes these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out myself. I installed Node—still don't know what it is exactly—but apparently I needed it. I found an installer package at http://nodejs.org/download/
Then I went back to Terminal and tried installing Bower again. Still didn't work. then I added sudo to the line and it appears to have worked.